# Internal Server Error while running docker-compose to install Gitlab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm installing **Gitlab** on my server using **docker-compose** based on [Docker Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose).
My SSH port is not the default one (22) and I have changed it to something else like 2228. So the YML file became like this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.mydomain.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain.com'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2228
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
    - '2228:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

When I run the `docker-compose up -d`, I receive this result and errors:

```
Starting docker_web_1 ...

ERROR: for docker_web_1  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

ERROR: for web  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.21/containers/9d4483106cf1683f46b5158a9550f9b4375d7c147ecb8b07df533840ad0806b6/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compose/service.py", line 625, in start_container
  File "compose/container.py", line 241, in start
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1095, in start
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker_web_1 (9b32d28cc2f635e085e82a2ef9f4d1fd3afc76f7693e279405ada5f61b96d215): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1107, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1103, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 570, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
  File "compose/project.py", line 556, in do
  File "compose/service.py", line 568, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "compose/service.py", line 510, in _execute_convergence_start
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 112, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 210, in producer
  File "compose/service.py", line 508, in <lambda>
  File "compose/service.py", line 620, in start_container_if_stopped
  File "compose/service.py", line 627, in start_container
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
[5738] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I'm new in Docker and docker-compose, but I did everything as it is written in the official documentation. May you help me plesae to solve this issue?

Comment: `listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use` It seems that the 443 port on your system is not available. Please check whether this port is available before starting these docker images or choose another port.

Comment: why would this prevent building the image?  I can see that it would impact running a container.

Answer (score 4):

In the error message you presented your system is reporting port 443 is already in use. You need to confirm which ports you have in use for other services.

> listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

For what it is worth I recommend you use a nginx reverse proxy. Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195852/how-to-run-gitlab-in-docker-container-with-nginx-proxy-over-ssl-with-letsencrypt for further details.